# How to delete a row if it is a unique entry in R?

Tags: r, row, unique

Hopefully I have a simple question. How to remove the rows that have a unique date, i.e. there is only one entry with that date in the whole dataset. I want to do this because I am analyzing within group differences. The tests will not run with groups that are less than 2.

I look forward to your insights.

Comment: `df[duplicated(df$Date)|duplicated(df$Date, fromLast=T),]`

Comment: `df[!unique(df$Date),]`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(Date= sample(seq(as.Date("2001-05-05"), by=2, length.out=5),7, replace=T))

df[duplicated(df$Date)|duplicated(df$Date, fromLast=T),,drop=F]
#         Date
 # 1 2001-05-13
 # 2 2001-05-13
 # 4 2001-05-13
 # 5 2001-05-11
 # 7 2001-05-11
```